# Ingrate AdminLTE with laravel 5.4:css and js are not loading

Tags: php, laravel-5, npm, adminlte

Trying to intagrate popular admin dashaboard (Adminlte) into my latest laravel

Steps i followed

1.Downloaded admin-lte via npm install --save admin-lte.

2.In my `app.js` file included the following line  `require('admin-lte')`.

3.Finally i build the project with `npm run build`

In my `home.blade,php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body class="skin-blue">
    <!--dmi lte pages  -->

       <!--Jascript all files --->
       <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is styles are not loading...

Since we using laravel mix (Its like gulp build) i think there is no need to include the css and js seprately.

Comment: Got same issue with js, in my case adminlte js is not loading. Did you find out the issue?